# Question on Measurable function on $L^P$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $p$ be number such that $1\le p < \infty$. Suppose $f_n, n \ge 1$, is a sequence of $M-$measuarable function on $X$ such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ $\mu-$almost everywhere on $X$. Suppose also that $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$ for all $n\ge1$ and $x\in X$ , where $g\in L^p$.

How to prove that  $\left\lVert f-f_n \right\rVert_p \rightarrow 0$ as $ n\rightarrow \infty$.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is $\mu$ $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I apologize.  For whatever reason, I misread your assumption as $f_n\to f$ in measure, in which case you do need $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite.  But as written, this is not so messy, as you  essentially run through the proof of LDCT again (as in the answer of Umberto).  If it is convergence in measure, you work with a subsequence of $f_n$, and the details get a bit messy.

Comment: Its okay... and thanks for you comment.I am sorry for all the detail !

Comment: Perfectly fine.  It's a problem I've worked out in the past.  Essentially, you need to prove it in the case $p=1$ and then you can use an argument similar to Umberto's answer to generalize to $1\leq p < \infty$.  It's an interesting exercise, but is a bit involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove this like you prove LDCT: use the basic inequality $|a+b|^p \le 2^p(|a|^p + |b|^p)$ to obtain 
$$
2^p |f_n|^p + 2^p |f|^p - |f_n - f|^p \ge 0.
$$
Since $|f_n| \le g$ almost everywhere and $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, you also have $|f| \le g$ almost everywhere. Thus
$$2^{p+1} g^p - |f_n - f|^p \ge 0.
$$
Now apply the Fatou lemma:
$$
\int_X 2^{p+1} g^p \, d\mu = \int_X \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 2^{p+1} g^p - |f_n - f|^p \right) \, d\mu \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_X \left( 2^{p+1} g^p - |f_n - f|^p \right) \, d\mu.$$
Some basic properties of the liminf imply
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_X \left( 2^{p+1} g^p - |f_n - f|^p \right) \, d\mu = \int_X 2^{p+1} g^p \, d\mu - \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_X |f_n - f|^p \, d\mu.$$
Thus
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_X |f_n - f|^p \, d\mu \le 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just try to understand it. and I will accept as answer. thanks

Comment: If you have a further question go ahead and ask. If you're not accustomed to liminf/limsup it can be a bit difficult to work with.

Comment: befroe last line I think there should be $g^p$ instead of $g$.thanks